# get all the numbers (telephone) of a contact? (in android 2.1)

Tags: android

guys, anybody has a code snippet where I can get all the numbers (telephone) of a contact? (in android 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

using Telephony.Contact.CONTENT_URI，
try it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) at the android-developer-site.